# Node writeFileSync encoding options for images

Tags: node.js, encoding, electron, writefile

I'm using `fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])` to save a file returned from `http.get(options[, callback])`

This works fine for text files but images, pdfs etc end up being corrupted. From the searching around that I've done, it's apparently because `fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])` defaults to UTF-8

I've tried setting the encoding to 'binary', the mime-type and the extension to no avail. It feels like something really obvious that I'm overlooking, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance

**Update**

I'm running this through electron. I didn't think it was worth mentioning as electron is just running node, but I'm not a node or electron expert so I'm not sure

Comment: In my case my api response pdf data into stream and I am trying to download that pdf data stream into pdf by using fs.writeFile or fs.writeFileSync method. I am getting blank pdfs. I had try adding encoding binary in request header and also in fs methods. I am running my app in electron. Thanks for mentioning electron in your updated question. Can you throw some light on this or where am i wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Buffer from the image data and set its encoding to `binary`. Then pass that data into a `stream.PassThrough` and pipe that into a `stream.Writable`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = require('stream');

var imgStream = new stream.PassThrough();
imgStream.end(Buffer.from(data, 'binary'));

var wStream = fs.createWriteStream('./<dest>.<ext>');

imgStream.once('end', () => {
    console.log('Image Written');
});

imgStream.once('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

imgStream.pipe(wStream);
```

Comment: Hi @peteb. Thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion and every file threw an error to the effect of `Unknown encoding: %pdf-1.4` in the case of pdf files. Image files didn't appear to throw any errors but the images were still corrupt and therefore unreadable. I've updated my question to include the fact that I'm running this through electron, although I'm not sure how relevant that is

Comment: The solution was to set the request encoding to 'binary' however, as you suggest, it also requires the buffer encoding set to 'binary' too. I've been trying both of these methods for the past 2 days but never together (why is beyond me). But doing so seems to have solved my issue, so I'll mark you correct as it contains a part of the solution. Thanks for your help